# Inclusion and Exclusion Word Problem: Discrete Math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

I am having trouble understanding how to solve this question:

> Some five courses are offered in a semester. The group of students who take at least
> one of these courses consists of 155 students. There are 80 students registered in each
> course. For any two among these courses, there are precisely 40 students who take
> each of them. For any three of these courses, there are precisely 20 students who take
> each of them. For any four among these courses, there are precisely 10 students who
> take each of them. How many students in this group take every one among the five
> courses in this semester?

What I came up with is using a diagram I created to try and figure the problem out.

> Course 1: has 40 people unaccounted for.
>
> Course 2: has 30 people unaccounted for.
>
> Courses 3 & 4 & 5: has 50 people unaccounted for.

By this process, only 30 people can take all five classes, but that leaves out 10 people in course 1 and 20 people in courses 3, 4 and 5.

This question comes from some inclusion/exclusion notes from my professor. The notes don't really explain inclusion/exclusion very well, or at least I don't understand it.

What am I missing? Can someone help me understand how to solve this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although a Venn diagram can be very helpful in the case of $3$ events (courses), it is of diminishing helpfulness as the number of courses grows.

Call the courses $A,B,C,D,E$, or even $C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4,C_5$. There are $80$ people taking each of the $5$ courses.

If we add up the numbers of people taking the various courses, we get $5\cdot 80$. This is far bigger than the total of $155$ students. The reason is clear: we have "double-counted" the people who are taking both courses $A$ and $B$, also $A$ and $C$, and so on for all combinations of $2$ courses. There are $\binom{5}{2}=10$ such combinations.

Each such combination of $2$ courses is taken by $40$ students. If we subtract the number of courses taken by both $A$ and $B$, also the courses taken by $A$ and $C$, and so on, we should get closer to $155$. So the count of students should be closer to $5\cdot 80-10\cdot 40$.

But we have subtracted too much! For we have subtracted too many times the people who are taking $3$ of the courses. There are $\binom{5}{3}=10$ such combinations of courses, each taken by $20$ students, for a total of $10\cdot 20$. Thus the number of students should be closer to $5\cdot 80-10\cdot 40+10\cdot 20$.

However, we have added back too much, the $\binom{5}{4}=5$ combinations of $4$ courses. So we should subtract $5\cdot 10$.

The total number of students should therefore be close to $5\cdot 80-10\cdot 40+10\cdot 40-5\cdot 10$.  This is almost right, except that we have subtracted once too many times the $x$ students taking all five courses. It follows that
$$155=5\cdot 80-10\cdot 40+10\cdot 20-5\cdot 10+x.$$
Now we can find $x$.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I would have never thought to add and subtract the combinations like that. Thanks for the help; that was very informative!

Comment: You are welcome. The Inclusion/Exclusion process in this case is "too long" for a first exposure to PIE. I would have preferred $3$ courses, or $4$ at most.